# FlatList scroll does not work inside ScrollView

Tags: react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I have FlatList which is inside scrollView but I can not scroll flat list when I scrolling through app screen. I was googling but I didn't find proper solution to this problem. Can you please help me, I don't know what's wrong...

My code:

```
<ScrollView>
       <FlatList
                                     ref={(list) => this.myList = list}
                                    style={styles.flatList}
                                    data={this.state.data}
                                    scrollEnabled = {true}
                                    //showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                    contentContainerStyle={{ padding: 15 }}
                                    renderItem={({ item }) => (

                                          <View style={styles.listItemStyle}>
                                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row', marginBottom: 7, }}>

                                                {
                                                    item.checked && 
                                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                                        onPress={this.changeCheckedToFalse.bind(this,item)}>
                                                        <View style={styles.checked} /> 
                                                    </TouchableOpacity> || 
                                                    <TouchableOpacity
                                                        onPress={this.changeCheckedToTrue.bind(this,item)}>
                                                        <View style={styles.unchecked} />
                                                    </TouchableOpacity>
                                                }


                                                <Text>{item.key}</Text>
                                                {
                                                    item.checked &&
                                                    <View style={{position: 'absolute', right: 0 }}>
                                                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}} >
                                                            <TouchableOpacity 
                                                                style={[styles.touchable1,styles.iconStyle1]} >

                                                                <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 15, alignSelf: 'center' }}>O</Text>
                                                            </TouchableOpacity>


                                                            <TouchableOpacity 
                                                                style={[styles.touchable2,styles.iconStyle1]} >
                                                                <Text style={{color: '#fff', fontSize: 15, alignSelf: 'center' }}>N</Text>
                                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                                        </View>
                                                    </View>
                                                }
                                            </View>

                                            <View style={styles.line} />
                                          </View>



                                    )}
                                    keyExtractor={item => item.key}
                                />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: scrollview inside a scrollview is a very bad idea! you have to disable the scroll of one of them.

Comment: But I have a lot items on that screen and also my FlatList would have a lot of users.

Comment: How can I disable scroll of one of them ?

Comment: the best idea would to redesign the page and split it into two different pages or make the flatlist scroll horizontally or maybe disable the scroll of the flatlist and make the size equal to the sum of row's size

Comment: this is how you can disable the scroll if you want https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/14240

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Container instead of ScrollView. In below code both scrolling are working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Image, Text, FlatList, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { Container, Content } from 'native-base'

const dimensions = Dimensions.get('window');
const viewHeight = Math.round(dimensions.width * 9 / 16);
const viewWidth = dimensions.width;

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = { FlatListItems: [
                {key: 'One'},
                {key: 'Two'},
                {key: 'Three'},
                {key: 'Four'},
                {key: 'Five'},
                {key: 'Six'},
                {key: 'Seven'},
                {key: 'Eight'},
                {key: 'Nine'},
                {key: 'Ten'},
                {key: 'Eleven'},
                {key: 'Twelve'}
            ]}
    }

    FlatListItemSeparator = () => {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 1,
                    width: "100%",
                    backgroundColor: "#607D8B",
                }}
            />
        );
    }

    GetItem (item) {
        Alert.alert(item);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <View style={{
                        height: 150
                    }}>
                        <FlatList

                            data={ this.state.FlatListItems }

                            ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}

                            renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={styles.item} onPress={this.GetItem.bind(this, item.key)} > {item.key} </Text>}
                        />
                    </View>


                    <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>Scroll me plz</Text>
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Text style={{fontSize:96}}>If you like</Text>
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                    <Image source={{uri: "https://facebook.github.io/react-native/img/favicon.png", width: 64, height: 64}} />
                </Content>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    item: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        height: 44,
    },

});

export default App;
```